# Amazon RDS automated backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-rds, database-backups

I can see from the AWS console that my RDS instance is being backed up once a day. From the FAQ I understand that it is being backup on S3. But when I use the console to view my S3 buckets, I don't see the RDS backup.

So:

1. How do I get my hands on my RDS backup?
2. Once I have it how do I use it to restore my DB i.e is it a regular mysqldump file or something else?

Answer (score 8):

OK - I see it under the DB snapshots, Automated Snapshots (Had it selected to Manual Snapshots and hence could not see it)

Comment: Are you able to download these snapshots to your local machine? I'm trying to access my backup on my local machine, but it doesn't seem possible on AWS.

Answer (score 8):

RDS snapshot as well as EBS snapsots are stored in S3, but not accesible via the S3 interface. 
You can restore a whole database be clicking "Restore Snapshot" from the AWS Management Console.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to have .sql backups manually, you can also use the script I've been developing:

https://github.com/Ardakilic/backmeup

This script backups your SQL databases along with your webhost root to your S3 or Dropbox. So this means, you can dump any SQL from any host (RDS or any other provider) and upload them to S3. It uses aws-cli as backend.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what I did is I wrote a simple bash script to do this for me, but I works fine in a single region, it doesnt work with multiple regions, here is the script http://geekospace.com/back-up-and-restore-the-database-between-two-aws-ec2-instances/